# Code review plugin running tests at source code level

Tags: devops, static-code-analysis

I am building a Devops pipeline , where in I am trying to include an extra code review plugin which supports **C, C++ and C#**. In my pipeline, I already have Sonarqube 6.5 running and it also has the FXCop plugin activated.

So, Sonarqube runs tests at source code level and FXCop runs tests at binary level. Now, I am trying to find out another code review plugin which could be plugged to Sonarqube (Plugin has to run tests at source code level, not binary level).

I thought of choosing **StyleCop** but it has to be downloaded in my laptop. So, I had to neglect that.
Tried using **Source Meter**, which is another plugin that runs review tests at source code level but it is not compatible with 6.5 version of Sonarqube (only supported till Sonarqube 4.5 version).

And now, I am running out of plugins which could do the job. Could anyone suggest a plugin that could both be plugged with Sonarqube 6.5 and run source code level review tests?

**NOTE: (Should support C, C++ and C#)**

Answer (score 1):

You could try SonarQube plug-in for [PVS-Studio](https://www.viva64.com/en/m/0037/) static source code analyzer for C/C++/C#.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul. Does Soanrqube 6.5 support this plugin? Please let me know.

Comment: Yes, it should support Soanrqube 6.5.